# Looking within a directory for a file

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I have written this code to build a list by looking inside directory within deep to the level it finds a audio file and then move to the next level or next folder.

Can there be a more efficient way since a user can have any number of files? Do you think it can be achieved more robustly in terms of performance?

```
path = '/Users/ceaser/Music'

import os
allSongs = []
for folder in os.walk(path):
    for item in folder[-1]:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
        if ext in ['.mp3', '.wma', '.wav', '.ogg']:
            allSongs.append(name)
```

Comment: os.listdir is faster then os.walk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of this will largely depend on filesystem I/O,
and the number of files and subdirectories in your target folder.

It won't make a difference in practice,
but in theory it will be faster to check the extension against a set instead of a list, for example:

```
extensions = {'.mp3', '.wma', '.wav', '.ogg'}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for item in filenames:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
        if ext in extensions:
            allSongs.append(name)
```

Notice that I changed the `for folder in os.walk(path)` to the more intuitive `for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path)`,
which makes the inner loop more intuitive too,
`for item in filenames` instead of the cryptic `for item in folder[-1]`.

But most of all,
I'm wondering if it's really `os.walk` you want to use.
This function is useful for traversing a directory tree,
down into arbitrary levels of subdirectories.
I'm questioning your intention because you only keep filenames, not their paths.
So for example a song `The Four Horsemen.mp3` may exist in both `/Users/ceaser/Music/Metallica` and in `/Users/ceaser/Music/Mix/Oldies-But-Goodies`, and then you will have `The Four Horsemen.mp3` in `allSongs` twice.
Not caring about the intermediary directories suggests that perhaps there are no intermediary directories, all songs are simply directly under `/Users/ceaser/Music`.
In that case, instead of `os.walk`, using `os.listdir` would be more appropriate and simpler too.

Lastly, there is an official coding style guide for Python,
called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
I recommend to give it a good read and follow it in the future.

Comment: i think using `listdir` we would need to go by recursive function approach which I was thinking will be adding extra overhead

Comment: I recommended listdir only in the case if you have a flat directory layout. If you have subdirectories then os.walk is simple and fine. It seems you misunderstood my post